# @Html.TextBoxFor text changed event

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have an `@Html.TextBoxFor` as below :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.SomeProperty, new { @class = "jtb", @id = "TrajName", placeholder = "Traj Name" })
```

Now what I want to achieve is I want to know when a new character is added to this textbox at the same time it is entered.
I want to change a button state to active at this time. I tried `blur` and `change` event. But it is fired only when the focus changes.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#TrajName').val("");
    $('#StartLocation').val("-Select Location-");
    $('#EndLocation').val("-Select Location-");

    document.getElementById("BtnAddTraj").disabled = true;

    $("#TrajectoryName").blur(function () {
        if ($('#TrajName').text != "")
            document.getElementById("BtnAddTraj").disabled = false;
        else
            document.getElementById("BtnAddTraj").disabled = true;
    });
});
```

I have a scenario where user can directly try to click on the button after entering some text(ie cursor still inside textbox and focus is not changed).

So is there any event that gives live trigger when a character is added instead of firing on focus change?

Comment: Use `.keyup()`.

Comment: `#TrajName` is an input so its `if ($('#TrajName').val() != "")`

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Thanks. It worked. I have a doubt. Both `.val()` and `.text` of the textboxfor will return the same thing right? ie the text value of the textbox

Comment: No, `text` will not return anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to bind an event handler to the `keyup` JavaScript event.

Further more, I recommend you to use `.prop` for set disabled property.

Please try this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.SomeProperty, new { @class = "jtb", @id = "TrajName", placeholder = "Traj Name" }) 

 $("#TrajectoryName").keyup(function () {
    if ($('#TrajName').val() != "")
        $("#BtnAddTraj").prop('disabled',false);
    else
        $("#BtnAddTraj").prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Another solution is to trigger the `input` event to the `TrajectoryName` textbox. This would fire every time your input changes.

```
$("#TrajectoryName").on('input',function () {
    if ($('#TrajName').val() != "")
        $("#BtnAddTraj").prop('disabled',false);
    else
        $("#BtnAddTraj").prop('disabled',true);
});
```